# Search Foobar library by codec or filetype?

Tags: foobar2000

Is it possible to return matches of a codec or filetype?

Example use case: I want the FLAC version of an album name "foo", but I have the FLAC and AAC version in my library.

At the moment search will return a distinct list of songs for the album foo, but they explode into dupes when dragged to a playlist. I then have to weed out the unwanted dupes with control-clicking after determining which coded is which.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In foobar open the *Media Library Search* window and use this search pattern

```
%album% HAS foo AND %codec% IS MP3
```

[image]

### More search operators with example

```
HAS                 %path% HAS "C:\my music"
IS                  %directoryname% IS dubstep

AND                 %title% HAS foo AND %codec% IS MP3  
OR                  %artist% HAS "foo bar" OR %title% MISSING
NOT                 NOT %last_played% AFTER %first_played%

DURING LAST         %last_played% DURING LAST 3 WEEKS (SECONDS/MINUTES/HOURS/DAYS)
DURING              %last_modified% DURING 2011
AFTER               %last_played% AFTER 2012-02
BEFORE              %last_modified% BEFORE 2013-02-31
SINCE               %last_played% SINCE 2014-02-31 05:45:00

EQUAL               %discnumber% EQUAL 4    
GREATER             %filesize_natural% GREATER 10   
LESS                %bitrate% LESS 128  

MISSING             %rating% MISSING    
PRESENT             %_dynamic_rating% PRESENT   

SORT BY             SORT BY %play_count%
SORT DESCENDING BY  SORT DESCENDING BY %last_played%
```

- [Reference for search syntax](http://wiki.hydrogenaud.io/index.php?title=Foobar2000:Query_syntax)
- [Reference for valid field names](http://wiki.hydrogenaud.io/index.php?title=Foobar2000:Title_Formatting_Reference)